# My add-ons are not updating when tor browser is restarted

Tags: add-on, noscript

My add-ons are not updating, no matter how many times I restart tor browser. In my add-ons tab I have these messages:

```
HTTPS-Everywhere will be updated after you restart Tor Browser. 

NoScript will be updated after you restart Tor Browser. 

Tab Mix Plus will be updated after you restart Tor Browser.
```

And in the grayed-out section at the bottom of the add-ons tab I see the updates have been downloaded, but not installed over the old versions:

```
Tab Mix Plus will be installed after you restart Tor Browser. 

DownThemAll! will be installed after you restart Tor Browser. 

NoScript will be installed after you restart Tor Browser. 

HTTPS-Everywhere will be installed after you restart Tor Browser.
```

What is stopping these updates and new add-ons? What can I do to fix it?

PS: I tried a fresh install of TBB, but the same issue prevails. It seems to have crept in somewhere as new versions of TBB were produced.

PPS: It would be good if a Tag was available for HTTPS-Everywhere.

Additional info: OS is Windows 8. Tor installation is on external HD. Updates to Tor itself are successful, but I'm stuck with outdated add-ons. If anybody knows a way to force TBB to accept the add-on updates I'd very much appreciate it.

More info: I copied my Tor Browser folder to a different external device and ran it from there, but the add-ons have still failed to update. I conclude this problem is not specific to a particular external device. As I had the same problem on a fresh installation, I also conclude it's not due to peculiarities in my installation. Ron, thanks for your suggestions (I don't have the ability to Comment underneath) but I'm not sure how they apply to my situation. No other versions of Firefox have trouble updating add-ons. I don't use Zone Alarm. Downloading the updates is not a problem. Applying the downloaded updates is the problem. I'd be happy to hear your further suggestions or clarifications, but StackExchange makes it very hard to respond to each other. What I'm doing now, editing the initial post, seems the only mode available for me to communicate.

Comment: extensions.update.enabled is "true"

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what OS you are using. I know that having a registry cleaner or guard active with Windows OS can restrict you registry from updating sometimes. Also I have had some issues between Zone Alarm and tor software which I fix by turning Zone Alarm off while downloading tor stuff so a non-native firewall (say - Zone Alarm as opposed to Windows Firewall) could be complicating your tor browser startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, for now at least. I moved the xpi files from the Staged folder to the Extensions folder, replacing outdated ones. This has brought my existing add-ons up to date, and has installed the new add-ons I wanted.

The cause of xpi files getting stuck in the Staged folder remains unexplained.